# How to read sms message on iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, bluetooth

I wanna make a application which can read SMS message through bluetooth headset automatically when it arrives.

I think this could be very useful when driving a car.

To do this,

1. able to detect SMS arriving.
2. able to get SMS text message.
3. able to encode SMS text as TTS stream.(I have my own TTS Engine, so this doesn't matter)
4. send stream through bluetooth headset which already paired.

Is there someone could help me? :)

Comment: Please do a search here before you ask a question. If you just searched for `iphone sms` you would see the hundreds of times this question has been asked before and the hundreds of useful answers.

Comment: @Matthew Frederick, this question is about reading not sending.

Comment: @Tom Then add `read` to the search for `sms` and the `[iphone]` tag; as noted it's been asked and answered hundreds of times.

Comment: See this link [get sms on jailbroken iphone][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10681995/how-to-get-the-message-when-receiving-the-kctmessagereceivednotification-notif/11026338#11026338

Answer (score 14):

it's not possible on standard iOS. The sms API is not exposed, hence interaction with the message application or database is not possible. 
Jailbroken Apps might be able to use the SMS interface somehow, tho. I would start going into that direction.