# How to delete SMS messages from iphone which are sent from an app?

Tags: ios, iphone, sms

In the app I need to verify the user's phone number and for that the app will be sending him a SMS text message. I want to delete this SMS after some time. I searched for it and found the path of messages which is `"/var/mobile/Library/SMS/sms.db"` and manipulate it through database browsers and so on.My questions are as follows.

1. Is there any simple code or method to achieve this delete task ?
2. Is it safe to manipulate the iphone messages or will it cause a problem when I upload my app to app store since apple has its own set of rules ?

Comment: You can only do it in Jailbroken devices, and apple will not allow your app for AppStore submission if you do such stuffs.

Comment: @Midhun.Okay thanks for the info,waiting for some more suggestions.

Comment: I _don't_ want your app deleting my SMS!!!

Comment: You can not access or delete sms messages using any public apis. You can access /var/mobile/Library/SMS/sms.db only jail broken devices. [check](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12118926/how-to-get-sms-from-iphone-xcode)

Comment: @novice : instead of that use OTP like methodology

Comment: @midhun :OTP wont satisfy the requirement.Its better I let that message stay.Actually the issue is that when the user receives the first message and things don't work as expected or any issue arises I would be sending him the message with validation code two more times,and so I wanted to delete the previous messages.