# to get sms stats in application

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, jailbreak

In my application I want to get the total number of SMS sent from iPhone. My application is targeted for cydia store for jail broken devices and Currently I am working on xcode 4.5.2 and iOS 6.

When the application opens I want to get the total SMS sent from iPhone message log. Can we get total SMS sent on a particular day. I saw some applications in cydia store which maintains SMS history logs for example"SMS Stats", "SMS Counter". Is there any third party framework to get sms count?. I had searched in many ways but I found no solution. Please help me.

Comment: make sure to look over [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11026338/119114)

Answer (score 1):

The messages are kept in a SQLite database called `sms.db`

You can make queries on it to collect the information you want.

At [theiphonewiki](http://theiphonewiki.com/wiki/index.php?title=IMessage#Main_database_file) got some information about the DB but I am not sure it is updated to iOS 6, you might just have to investigate the DB using some SQLite explorer to figure out what you need.