# How to install Xcoded ipa into /Applications/

Tags: xcode, sms, jailbreak

I am using ios 5.1.1 jailbroken iphone.
I read through Nate's solution [how to get the message when receiving the "kCTMessageReceivedNotification" notification on IOS5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10681995/how-to-get-the-message-when-receiving-the-kctmessagereceivednotification-notif/11026338#11026338) and successfully build ipa.
But how could I install it into /Applications/?
I tried to use iFunbox, or some other tools, they all install it in sandbox (/private/....) folder and it failed to open sms.db.

Could anyone guide?

Comment: You don't need ipa. Build your app and copy *.app folder into /Applications/ on your device. Then respring.

Comment: Actually a respring won't show the icon; you need to force the icon cache to be reloaded with `uicache` (you must run this as the `mobile` user)

Comment: hi kirb, it didn't give me chance to verify. I have extract xx.app folder and directly put into /Applications. When i install "respring", my device was dead. So I did restart, the icon is there. However, clicking my app icon, it quickly flashed once, as if it displayed alreayed but quit straight away. Please note if I install the ipa in normal, it worked.

Comment: by the way, I have used ifile to verify the permission of xx.app folder in /Applications/ is 777

Comment: You need to set permissions for the app binary, not xx.app folder. That's why it quits right away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take Your .ipa file and extract it with something like 7zip. There should be a folder called "Payload." Drop the ".app" folder in there into /Applications/. Then SSH into your iPhone and run `chmod -R 777 /Applications/<yourappname>.app/`

Comment: This approach worked! I also proved creker's solution. Thank you all. Sorry, taconut, I can't vote your solution as i don't have sufficient permission but your approach (also creker's) worked.

Comment: Actually, this is close, but not quite correct.  You don't rename the `Payload` folder.  You would simply copy the .app folder, that is *inside* the Payload folder.  There's also no need to set everything to `777` permissions.  Only the app binary needs to be executable, and it probably should have permissions 775 or 755.

Comment: Sorry about that. Its just easier to chmod -R rather that give the user 10-step instructions or make them execute a really long shell script. I'll edit my post and make it better.

Comment: Also, I'm thinking the shell script would be something like:
`$name = <yourAppName>;chmod -R 775 /Applications/$name.app/;chmod 777 /Applications/$name.app/$name`
I'm not the best with bash, so that may not be 100% accurate