# how to read reply SMS in objective-c

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I'm developing movie app and want read reply message for SMS in iOS 
I sent a message to the number 4888888 SMS. Later I received a reply from the number. I asked, I can read or access the message or not.

Comment: You can not do with Public API

Comment: for jail break device check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10681995/how-to-get-the-message-when-receiving-the-kctmessagereceivednotification-notif/11026338#11026338

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is NO way to read an sms in iOS. Apple does not allow that. The messages api allows you to use the [compose message](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMessageComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html) window, pre-populate it with data and let the user send a message within your app. 
But when it comes to reading incoming messages, there is no public api that gives you that option.

Comment: Apple introduced `oneTimeCode` from ios 12 to read otp from SMS.

Answer (score 1):

Apple does not allow developer to access message inbox to get the messages we can only send SMS/MMS from app

Answer (score 0):

1. Not possible.
2. [Check this](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMessageComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html)
3. For SMS sending through application allowed but for accessing inbox for SMS/email not allowed.

For sending text

```
NString *message = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"sms:%@",Phone_number_string];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:message]];
```