# Receive SMS Event on iPhone without Jailbreak?

Tags: ios, sms, iphone-privateapi

I read a lot of topics like these:
[How Can We Read Incoming SMS by using Application in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21300138/how-can-we-read-incoming-sms-by-using-application-in-ios)
[how to read reply SMS in objective-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20515763/how-to-read-reply-sms-in-objective-c)
[how to get the message when receiving the "kCTMessageReceivedNotification" notification on IOS5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10681995/how-to-get-the-message-when-receiving-the-kctmessagereceivednotification-notif/11026338#11026338)

I didn't get all the information, so I'm asking it again, directly. What I need is:

- on iOS 9 (The last link looks good, but it's iOS5. Many things have changed since then..)
- write an SMS (that seems easier)
- weceive Event of response SMS and read concent of that SMS
- no Jailbreak (important point, is it possible at all without jb?)
- no need for store deployment, so I don't care about Apple's guidelines in that point.

Does anyone know a way to realize that?
I prefer ObjC, but swift is also okay. Most important is to achieve this in the end.

*edit*

Why the down vote? Actually the one who says there is **No way at all** has to prove his absolute statement. I try to ask a precise question to a very specific task and a down vote without a written down reasen does not help anyone.

Comment: There is no way to get sms event  . . . . .With out jailbreak . . .It is not availble

Comment: Even with the use of Private Api? The last link looks like it was possible somehow. It's just old but it has never been part of the official Api.