# jailbreak non-appstore way to get received SMS (through iMessage as well) notification

Tags: ios, xcode, notifications, sms, jailbreak

I have looked all over and found many ways to send an SMS on IOS.

I'm wanting to capture a notification of an incoming SMS. This is personal on my own jailbroken iPhone so it can use private frameworks. I'm just looking for a method. I tried just using Notification Center and listening for everything but of course nothing come through when an SMS text is received.

I really don't want to just poll every so often reading the SMS DB if there is a notification method available.

FWIW, I think at least an SMS notification without access to the text should be public ;) I've written a really cool program on Android that automatically reads the text through TTS and allows you to respond through STT. I never have to touch my Android phone in the car. I wish I could do the same with an iPhone.

Comment: Did you even try to search? Here is solution (read the question) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10681995/how-to-get-the-message-when-receiving-the-kctmessagereceivednotification-notif?rq=1 I use it my projects. It will only give you notification and message type, nothing more.

Comment: Many thanks. I'll look into this. Again FWIW, I searched for endless hours through code and forums and stack. There are literally 1000's of entries all suggesting how to send an SMS and not receive. This is great thanks.

Comment: I am going to be moving to an iPhone soon so I'm just wanting to verify. Is the only way to get to the message body via JailBreak and directly reading the message database? Is it possible through private frameworks without jailbreak?

Comment: I found (unfortunately) the answer is no.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10681995/how-to-get-the-message-when-receiving-the-kctmessagereceivednotification-notif

Comment: Yes, it's possible to read SMS without jailbreak through private APIs only. It's somewhat limited but possible. I don't think there're answers for the case of a non-jailbroken device. I think it's better to ask another question specifically for non-jailbroken devices.