# Import ChatKit (i.e., Private Framework) OR using CKDBMessage somehow

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode6, iphone-privateapi

First - I know private frameworks/APIs won't get me to the AppStore, this is for private use/research only.

I can't get my project to compile with `ChatKit.framework`.

Basically I need to somehow init a  `CKDBMessage` object and get stuff from it.

The ***first*** approach I tried is to be able to call this:

```
    CKDBMessage* msg = [[CKDBMessage alloc] initWithRecordID:lastID];
    NSLog(@"GOT SMS: %@", msg.text);
```

I couldn't get it to compile with any combination of these solutions:

- Simply add only `CKDBMessage.h` to my project
- Add all the headers of `ChatKit.framework`
- Add also `ChatKit.framework` file itself

I have the headers and the framework file in `Headers` folder and I tried adding any/all of these build settings, both on recursive/non-recursive:

- Framework Search Paths -> `$(PROJECT_DIR)/Headers`
- Header Search Paths ->

  - `$(SRCROOT)/Headers/ChatKit.framework/Headers`
  - `$(SRCROOT)/Headers`
- User Header Search Paths ->

  - `$(SRCROOT)/Headers`
  - `$(SRCROOT)/Headers/ChatKit.framework/Headers`

Always Search User Paths is always on YES

The ***second*** thing I tried was to do everything at runtime, this is what I have:

```
Class CKDBMessage = NSClassFromString(@"CKDBMessage");// objc_getClass("CKDBMessage");

SEL sel = @selector(initWithRecordID:);

NSMethodSignature *signature = [CKDBMessage methodSignatureForSelector:sel];
NSInvocation *invocation = [NSInvocation invocationWithMethodSignature:signature];
invocation.selector = sel;
[invocation setArgument:&lastID atIndex:2];
[invocation invoke];

NSObject * msgWeak = [CKDBMessage alloc];
[invocation getReturnValue:&msgWeak];
NSObject *msg = msgWeak;

NSString *text = [msg performSelector:@selector(text)];

NSLog(@"text: %@", text);
```

Here I crash at `invocationWithMethodSignature:` because NSClassFromString returns nil instead of the class...

Any ideas on any of the two approaches?

This is for nonjailbroken, iOS8(.2), using Xcode6

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well not many people viewed this, but for the sake of our wiki community, I managed to solve this by adding the `CKDBMessage.h` file to my project (actually I added all the headers of `ChatKit` but I don't think it's necessary), than I loaded the framework dynamically with `dlopen` like so:

```
dlopen("/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ChatKit.framework/ChatKit", RTLD_LAZY)
```

So my full solution is:

```
dlopen("/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ChatKit.framework/ChatKit", RTLD_LAZY);

Class CKDBMessageClass = NSClassFromString(@"CKDBMessage");
CKDBMessage *msg = [[CKDBMessageClass alloc] initWithRecordID:lastID];

NSString *text = msg.text;
NSLog(@"text: %@", text);
```

Getting the ID of the last message involves another framework: `IMDPersistence`:

```
//SomeFile.h
// ...
//declare the function:
static int (*IMDMessageRecordGetMessagesSequenceNumber)();

// SomeFile.m
// ...
//open IMDPersistence framework
void *libHandleIMD = dlopen("/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IMDPersistence.framework/IMDPersistence", RTLD_LAZY);

//make/get symbol from framework + name
IMDMessageRecordGetMessagesSequenceNumber = (int (*)())dlsym(libHandleIMD, "IMDMessageRecordGetMessagesSequenceNumber");

// get id of last SMS from symbol
int lastID = IMDMessageRecordGetMessagesSequenceNumber();
```

Now you can use `lastID` to get the message contents...

Comment: Hi, can you share more details? dlopen, RTLD_LAZY shows errors. undeclared identifier

Comment: You must include #include <dlfcn.h> for dlopen. On my side I wanted to know where you got lastID from?

Comment: should be `CKDBMessage *msg = ...`

Comment: Hey @AvielGross this used to work great on iOS 10 and below. But on the latest iOS 11 Beta, I'm seeing this: `Database": __XPCIMDMessageStoreSendXPCMessage has failed`. Have you tried it there? Any ideas if it will be posible to make it work on 11? Thanks!

Comment: @Jan I have to admit I am pretty surprised it took Apple all the way to 11 to fix this... I am not really dealing with this anymore so unfortunately I have no clue on what should work... you can check a class dump of iOS 11, see what's there for messaging etc.

Comment: Hello Aviel, can you please post the solution in swift?  or an link to complete Xcode project,

Answer (score 1):

Currently, I am using XCode 10. here we can see one `MessagesKit.framework` in `PrivateFrameworks` path. `MessagesKit.framework` contains S`OMessageHelper` file where we can see `sendSMS` function.

Function :

```
(void)sendMessageText:(id)arg1 toRecipient:(id)arg2 withCompletionBlock:(CDUnknownBlockType)arg3;
```