# read sms message IOS 11 get warning XPCIMDMessageStoreSendXPCMessag.

Tags: ios, iphone

read sms message ios 11 by private api appear warning XPCIMDMessageStoreSendXPCMessag. What meaning this warning?

[Warning] "Database": __XPCIMDMessageStoreSendXPCMessage failed too many times...bailing!

Comment: How did you read the message from private API will you please include code here ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26642770/get-sms-broadcast-with-text-body-without-jailbreak-but-private-frameworks-in-ios

Comment: Which entitlement for mobileSMS database for read messages IOS 11