# How to read incoming SMS in iOS 11

Tags: ios, ios11

I'm not a real IOS developer but I know from doing my research it's not possible to read iPhone SMS because the app is going to be rejected by Apple and no public API available.

but what if I want to create an app for myself (I will never submit it to AppStore), I want to know from your experience if there is any private API (in iOS 11(.4)) that will allow me to read any incoming SMS so I can make immediate action on it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get SMS broadcast with text body without Jailbreak BUT private frameworks in IOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26642770/get-sms-broadcast-with-text-body-without-jailbreak-but-private-frameworks-in-ios)

Answer (score 0):

Reading One Time Password from sms is available after iOS 12  . Check the Official Documentation for [Enabling Password AutoFill on a Text Input View](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/password_autofill/enabling_password_autofill_on_a_text_input_view)