# Determine Number of Messages sent to a specific number on iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone

My fiancé and I are trying to make an info graphic for our wedding. One of the metrics that we thought might be fun would be to show the total number of texts or phone calls that we made to one another on our iPhones. I have searched the reports/bills from our wireless carrier, but I don't think this has the information. We have never deleted the text or call history on our phones and live in a 100% Apple ecosystem. Does anybody have suggestions on how we can find out this information? We're open to having to do a bit of work to get at this information (e.g. taking advantage of an API, scraping the back-up files, etc.) Thanks!

Comment: I appreciate your idea. But it is not possible in non-jailboken devices. There is no public API available for doing this.

Comment: @MidhunMP - thanks for the guidance. Do you know if it's possible if we jailbreak the device?

Comment: Check this - http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/43262/how-can-i-see-the-call-history-from-one-month-ago

Comment: @KingOfTheNerds: Check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10681995/how-to-get-the-message-when-receiving-the-kctmessagereceivednotification-notif