# Is there a cross platform framework that can access sms content for Android, iOS and Windows Phone?

Tags: android, ios, windows-phone-7, xamarin.ios, cross-platform

We want an easy way to collect examples of sms messages sent from one person to the other. I have gone through a lot of the documentation for frameworks such as Phonegap to see if I can access sms content and Monotouch seems to be the only one that "might" be able to do this on Android and iOS (http://androidapi.xamarin.com/?link=T:Android.Telephony.SmsManager).

I am an Android developer and can easily do this on Android but I don't know the first thing about iOS or WP7 so I was hopping I could just pull the data off those types of devices, parse it some how (like obfuscate the private data) and send it to our service.

It doesn't need to have a beautiful UI or even be an app. It could be a webpage that somehow gets access to the underlying providers.

Jared

Comment: What would be the purpose of such an effort, other than spying?  Are there any legitimate reasons for intercepting SMS messages?

Comment: Some people may want to backup their chat history: http://code.google.com/p/android-sms/wiki/UserGuide

Comment: backup private sms on server, is like backup my pizza in a dogs hut

Comment: As I mentioned, we are doing data collection to see what sms messages  contain in certain situations. We are using a medium sized, controlled group of volunteers and the app will obfuscate their private data. Hopefully that alleviates the concerns from whomever decided to -1 this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible on standard iOS. See this stackoverflow question: [How to read sms message on iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4653615/how-to-read-sms-message-on-ios)